# Problems with jquery mobile and asp:button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I've created a page and have some problems with jquery mobile button and asp: button. The problem is that the button is automatically placed inside another button (which can not be used) and I wonder why this happens and what I am doing wrong? See picture for the "Click" button.

Her is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
<h1>Navigasjon</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
        <p>Under finner du din geografiske posisjon</p>

        <div id="posisjon"></div>
            <script>

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function (pos) {
                document.getElementById('<%=breddeGrad.ClientID%>').value = pos.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById('<%=lengdeGrad.ClientID%>').value = pos.coords.longitude;
            }
            );
</script>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="breddeGrad" runat="server" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox> Breddegrad
        <br/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="lengdeGrad" runat="server" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox> Lengdegrad
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="DoSomething" Text="Click"/>
        </form>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="inline">
                <h1>Test</h1>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a picture of how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading jquery AND jquery mobile twice:

Here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
```

and here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
```

remove one of these blocks.

I don't see why you would use a beta over a release candidate so you probably want to remove the second block.